# How to execute a dynamic sql statement in sql*plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I would like to modify a value by using a dynamic sql statement. The example is choosen to be reproductible. I know that I don't need a dynamic sql statement for that.

```
variable a number =1;
print a
```

> 1

```
exec execute immediate 'select 2 into :a from dual'
```

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
 print a
```

> 1

1 is returned instead of 2, which means that my statement wasn't executed.

So, how can it be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INTO` should be out of `execute immediate`:

```
SQL> var a number = 1;
SQL> print a

         A
----------
         1

SQL> exec execute immediate 'select 2 from dual' into :a;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print a

         A
----------
         2

SQL>
```